# Adding an png image over a white canvas in numpy

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a png image, which has to be overlaid on a white canvas. The png image dimensions are 200*200. The canvas dimensions are 512*512.

```
#SOURCE IMAGE 
img=cv2.imread("xx.png")
import cv2
import numpy as np
img_1 = np.zeros([512,512,1],dtype=np.uint8)
img_1.fill(255)
# or img[:] = 255
cv2.imshow('Single Channel Window', img_1)
print("image shape: ", img_1.shape)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: when you say you want to put this image, where do you want to put the source image in the white canvas? centre? or top left ? or both dimensions match ?

Comment: I want to put the image in the center of white background

Comment: whats the shape of `img`?

Comment: 200,200 is the shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need now is to place image into white background. As image shape is `200X200` and white background shape is `512X512`, the image white margins is going to be `(512-200)/2 = 156`. So:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("xx.png", 0)
row, col = img.shape  # row = 200, col = 200

img_1 = np.zeros([512,512],dtype=np.uint8)
img_1.fill(255)

margin = (512 - row)//2  
img_1[margin: margin+row, margin: margin+column] =  img

cv2.imshow('Single Channel Window', img_1)
print("image shape: ", img_1.shape)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Its also possible to pad the original image with white pixels using [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) and get the same result. So, for this case:

```
img = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)

margin = (512 - 200)//2   
img_1 = np.pad(img, margin, 'constant', constant_values=255)
```

Answer (score 0):

here canvas is the white region, and img is your input image.

```
canvas = np.zeros((512,512,3))
canvas.fill(255)
img = cv2.imread("xx.png",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

canvas[canvas.shape[0]//2-img.shape[0]//2:canvas.shape[0]//2+img.shape[0]//2,
canvas.shape[1]//2-img.shape[1]//2:canvas.shape[1]//2+img.shape[1]//2] = img
```

This is a simplistic code, with an assumption that both your source and canvas are square and RGB images.

The flag cv2.IMREAD_COLOR is important, because the canvas is 3 channels. 
if you want to use grayscale, use 1 channel in canvas, and if you want to use png(alpha channel included) use 4 channels accordingly.